# Is there a way to see why documentation was deleted?

Tags: support, documentation

I had created a documentation topic somebody else had requested.

[This topic on shortcuts in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/8173/android-studio-shortcuts)

I went back today to add the mac part, but it had been deleted. I'm not so much bothered that it has been deleted, nor will I argue for undeletion, but I would like to avoid wasting time/effort in the future by learning why this topic was removed. (Typing out all those kbd tags was tedious.)

Is there a way for me to see what it was flagged for or any delete remarks? Because I don't seem to be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [link to the review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/115562?filter-tags=android) in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/revisions/8173) for the topic.

In this case:

> This topic duplicates material from other topics, is deprecated, is obsolete, or is otherwise superfluous.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Where do you find those? I get the option to view the topic prior to deletion only.

Comment: @NickCardoso: On that "prior to deletion" version, you can access the topic's edit history by clicking the "edited" link at the bottom of the page.